# How can i set a Column in a CompositeId mapping with NHibernate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, firebird

I have one Composite Id map with NHibernate and I want to set a column in all those Id's. Is that possibel?

```
public class MapProduction : ClassMap<Production>
{
    public MapProduction()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(c => c.ProductionCode)
            .KeyProperty(c => c.Cycle)
            .KeyProperty(c => c.Crop)
            .KeyProperty(c => c.TechnologyLevel);
        Map(c => c.Area).Column("A_ARE");
        Map(c => c.Productivity).Column("P_ARE");
        Map(c => c.syncStatus).ReadOnly();
    }
}
```

If i just have one id, I can set a Column, but with composite I can't.

How can I do  this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found how do this.
In CompositeId have one parameter for add a table reference.

```
public class MapProduction : ClassMap<Production>
{
    public MapProduction()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(c => c.ProductionCode, "P_PRO")
            .KeyProperty(c => c.Cycle, "C_CIC")
            .KeyProperty(c => c.Crop, "C_CUL")
            .KeyProperty(c => c.TechnologyLevel, "C_NVT");
        Map(c => c.Area).Column("A_ARE");
        Map(c => c.Productivity).Column("P_ARE");
        Map(c => c.syncStatus).ReadOnly();
    }
}
```